# Are there instances of Starfleet officers using the same authorization codes in more than one episode?

Tags: star-trek

Starfleet vessels have security codes (also known as command codes or authorization codes) that can enable or disable various systems on the ship.  Do we ever see a character provide the *same security code* in more than one episode?

Please do not give instances of characters using *different* codes.  [This question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/32642/102339) points out that the codes can be changed.  Furthermore, it is quite possible that an officer may have more than one code, each for a different purpose.
Therefore, demonstrating that a character uses more than one code proves nothing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, there are a few examples from Voyager.

Janeway uses the code "Janeway-Pi-1-1-0" in the season 2 episode 17, "Dreadnought:"

> JANEWAY: Computer, initiate the self-destruct sequence. **Authorisation Janeway pi one one zero.** Set it at twenty minutes.

and then again a few episodes later in season 2 episode 21, "Deadlock":

> JANEWAY 2: Move it, Ensign! That's an order! Computer, initiate the self-destruct sequence. **Authorisation Janeway pi one one zero.** Set at five minutes and mute voice warnings. Enable.

---

Later in season 7 episode 4, "Repression," Tuvok uses the code "Tuvok pi alpha" twice:

> TUVOK: **Security override Tuvok pi alpha.**
>
> TUVOK: Computer, override those security restrictions. **Authorisation Tuvok pi alpha.**

and again in season 7 episode 12, "Lineage:"

> TUVOK: Override **authorisation Tuvok pi alpha.**

Comment: I tried searching the scripts before you answered, but cannot find more than 5 matches in the entire franchise (there are much more examples on Memory Alpha). After reading your quotes, I noticed that I have searched for "Authorization", not "Authorisation" :)

Comment: To your credit, the correct American spelling is with a "z," and Star Trek is an American franchise. My strategy was to look examples on memory alpha that cited more than one episode, and then search the transcripts for the code itself to confirm.